# How to get user token using better discord

Tags: javascript, discord

I am making my plugin betterdiscord. My plugin will update the user's "about me" content in their profile. To update the "about me" content, I need to make a request to the discord API, but to make this request, I need a user token. Q: How do I get a user token in my betterdiscord plugin?

I tried a lot but couldn't find anything, if you give a solution or sources where it can be found, then I will be very grateful

Comment: This violates a lot of discord's security stuff. Getting a user token would give the developer (you) access to their whole account. I seriously doubt this would be easily to get from the client. This also violates discord "No account automation" TOS rule, so I'd be very careful about proceeding with this.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but if I ask the user for a token, then it needs to be saved to the configuration file, if I do this, then any plugin will be able to access my configuration files and the token, which is more dangerous than getting a token on startup plugin and storing it temporarily, and not all the time in a file

Answer (score 1):

Using your token directly is a good way to risk your account. There are other ways to programmatically update the about me that does not involve grabbing the token.

For example you can grab the dispatch function directly and use it to update the bio:

```js
const dispatch = BdApi.Webpack.getByStrings("USER_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_SET_PENDING_BIO", {searchExports: true});
dispatch("New bio");
```

Comment: Yes, it replaces the text in about me, but it doesn't save the changes. I mean, when I use this piece of code, I have to go to the Profiles tab and click Save changes from the bottom